# Asp.net Redirect from page to another page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, redirect

I have **Main page** and **popup page** in asp.net

**Main Page Onload**

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey", "openPopup();", true);
```

**Main Page Html:**

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" />
```

**Main Page Javascript:**

```
 function openPopup() { // In order to open popup
            var popup;
            popup = window.open("BilgiPopupYenileme.aspx", "Popup", "width=900, height=400,status= 1, resizable= no, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=1,menubar=no");
            popup.focus();
        }
```

**Popup Page HTML (BilgiPopupYenileme.aspx)**

```
<a href="#" id="customerNo" onclick="GetCustomerNo()"><%#Eval("customer_ID")%></a>
```

**Popup Page Javascript:**

```
function GetCustomerNo() {

if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {

var customerNo = document.getElementById("customerNo").text;
var customerName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName"); // I set customerno to txtName input which is inside of Main Page.

customerName.value = customerNo;

}}
```

**Question:**

CustomerName.Value gets Customer Number without any problem (No problem till here).

After i get CustomerName.Value in Main Page  , i need to post/redirect to another page how can i do this?

I tried to use setinterval however this did not work for me %100.How can i solve the problem after i set value to textbox in Main Page than redirect to another page ?

Thanks